# Meta Graph - Post_video_views for specific ad

Tags: facebook, url, facebook-graph-api

I need help with adding the below data (`post_video_views`) to my campaign Ad insight data:

> "Total number of times your video was viewed for more than 3 seconds."

I've been stuck in an endless loop of tryouts in Graph API Explorer, and was hoping for someone to help.

I have the following URL from my main meta account:

```
act_accountid/campaigns?fields=ads{name,insights{spend,clicks,impressions,reach,inline_link_clicks}}
```

And I wish to add the total number of times the video on the ad have been viewed for more than 3 seconds.

After some reading through the documentation, I learned this was no longer possible, since the old field has been deprecated (is this correctly understood?)

My idea was then to update the campaign URL, so that I get out the `page_id` through the creative field (I have multiple pages) and then use the following URL:

```
Page_id/posts?fields=insights.metric(post_video_views).period(day)
```

I am however unsure how to connect these two data sources, so that I get the correct `post_video_views` added to my campaign ad data.

Any help is appreciated.